# Google geocoding returns zero results, Unity3D

Tags: google-maps, unity-game-engine, google-geocoder

I am trying to connect to google maps api and get lant/long of place, but no matter what I'm trying to get, I receive ZERO_RESULTS every time. For example if I type
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Moscow+Tverskaya+18 into browser, it gives me correct result, but if I'm trying to send the exact same string via WWW class from unity I get zero results.

```
  IEnumerator GetGoogleCoords() {
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
    var qs = "";
  // qs += "address=" + savedAddress;
    qs += "address=Moscow +Tverskaya+18";
    var req = new WWW(url + "?" + qs);
    Debug.Log(url + qs);
    yield return req;
    Debug.Log(req.text);

}
```

I tried every request and in every order

Comment: You are adding an extra "?" on `new WWW`. You're passing http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json??address=Moscow+Tverskaya+18. On browser it gives ZERO_RESULTS

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra "?" in your url as @Engerlost said.

This post is about how to prevent doing similar mistakes again.

Best programming practice would be to build the full url not in WWW constructor but in a separate line.

```
var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
var qs = "address=Moscow +Tverskaya+18";
var fullUrl = url + "?" + qs
var request = new WWW(fullUrl);
```

That is, one line should contain only one job. Which makes it much easier to manage the code. In your case, it gets much easier to debug and see there is an error building the full url. Now you are able to easily add a `Debug.Log` if you suspicious about final url which goes into WWW as parameter.

```
Debug.Log("Request url: " + fullUrl);
```

And you would easily see the resulting url contains two "?" characters.